# Reverse digits and add until a palindrome appears

Tags: algorithm, c, programming-challenge, palindrome

The following code is a C solution to the following problem [UVA 10018](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=24&page=show_problem&problem=959).

> **The Problem**
>
> The "reverse and add" method is simple: choose a number, reverse its
>   digits and add it to the original. If the sum is not a palindrome
>   (which means, it is not the same number from left to right and right
>   to left), repeat this procedure.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> 195 Initial number
> 591
>
> 786
> 687
>
> 1473
> 3741
>
> 5214
> 4125
>
> 9339 Resulting palindrome
> ```
>
> In this particular case the palindrome 9339 appeared after the 4th
>   addition. This method leads to palindromes in a few step for almost
>   all of the integers. But there are interesting exceptions. 196 is the
>   first number for which no palindrome has been found. It is not proven
>   though, that there is no such a palindrome.
>
> **Task**
>
> You must write a program that give the resulting palindrome and the
>   number of iterations (additions) to compute the palindrome.
>
> You might assume that all tests data on this problem:
>
> - will have an answer
> - will be computable with less than 1000 iterations (additions)
> - will yield a palindrome that is not greater than 4,294,967,295.
>
> **The Input**
>
> The first line will have a number N with the number of test cases, the
>   next N lines will have a number P to compute its palindrome.
>
> **The Output**
>
> For each of the N tests you will have to write a line with the
>   following data : minimum number of iterations (additions) to get to
>   the palindrome and the resulting palindrome itself separated by one
>   space.
>
> **Sample Input**
>
> ```
> 3
> 195
> 265
> 750
> ```
>
> **Sample Output**
>
> ```
> 4 9339
> 5 45254
> 3 6666
> ```

My solution is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* only works for unsigned longs */
unsigned long reverse(unsigned long original)
{
  unsigned long number = original;
  unsigned long reversed = 0;
  unsigned long place = 1;
  unsigned long i, q;

  for(i = 1000000000; i > 0; i = i / 10) {

    q = number / i;

    if ((q > 0) || (reversed > 0)) {
      reversed = reversed + (q * place);
      number = number - (q * i);
      place = place * 10;
    }
  }

  return(reversed);
}

int is_palindrome(unsigned long original)
{
  unsigned long reversed;
  reversed = reverse(original);
  return(reversed == original);
}

unsigned long reverse_add(unsigned long original, int *iterations)
{
  if (is_palindrome(original)) {
    return(original);
  }

  if (*iterations >= 1000) {
    return(0);
  }

  *iterations = *iterations + 1;
  reverse_add(original + reverse(original), iterations);
}

int main()
{
  int n = 0;
  unsigned long start;
  unsigned long end;
  int iterations = 0;

  while (scanf("%ld\n", &start) == 1) {
    if (n == 0) {
      n = start;
    }
    else {
      iterations = 0;
      end = reverse_add(start, &iterations);
      printf("%d %ld\n", iterations, end);
    }
  }

  return(0);
}
```

Comment: 196 never becomes a palindrome, even after 1000 steps. But 0196 does: 6910 + 196 is 7106. 7106 + 6017 = 13123. 13123 + 32131 = 45254.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### `reverse()`

Your `reverse()` function only works for numbers below 10<sup>10</sup>.  Although that upper bound may be good enough to solve this particular challenge, it's not correct in general.  (Keep in mind that the standard says that an `unsigned long` is *at least* 32 bits — possibly larger.)

Here is a simpler implementation that works in general:

```
unsigned long reverse(unsigned long original) {
    unsigned long reversed = 0;
    for (; original; original /= 10) {
        reversed = (10 * reversed) + (original % 10);
    }
    return reversed;
}
```

### `is_palindrome()`

For every iteration, you end up calling `reverse()` twice: once to test whether a palindrome has appeared, and again to obtain the next number to add.  You would be better off eliminating this function, and rolling the palindrome check into the `reverse_add()` loop itself.

### `reverse_add()`

For clarity, I would rename the function to `reverse_add_until_paindrome()`.

Conventionally, C functions are designed so that a status code is returned, and the data being manipulated are passed by reference.  I recommend redesigning the interface so that it returns the number of iterations, as that is closer in spirit to a status code.  The number itself can be passed by reference.  Notice what happens then: it becomes an in-out parameter!  The rationale for the convention makes itself apparent.

```
int reverse_add_until_palindrome(unsigned long *n) {
    int i;
    unsigned long rev;
    for (i = 0; (rev = reverse(*n)) != *n; i++) {
        *n += rev;
    }
    return i;
}
```

The problem statement guarantees that you will never be given a *P* that will require more than 1000 iterations.  That's just for your information; I don't think you need to verify that fact.  (If you do want to bail out, you should add code in `main()` to detect that the computation was aborted.)

### `main()`

The way you try to use one `scanf()` to read both *N* and the *P<sub>i</sub>* is awkward.  Not only does that make the code less clear, it also imposes a penalty of an extra conditional on every subsequent loop.  In addition, it's wrong: the format string for an `int` is `"%d"`, whereas the format string for an `unsigned long` is `"%lu"`.

You read `n`, but never make use of it.  That works, I suppose.  I prefer to use it to see whether all of the expected input was received.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int n;
    unsigned long p;

    if (1 != scanf("%d", &n)) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    while (n-- && scanf("%lu", &p)) {
        int iterations = reverse_add_until_palindrome(&p);
        printf("%d %lu\n", iterations, p);
    }
    return (n == 0) ? EXIT_SUCCESS : EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Missing return

This line:

> ```
> reverse_add(original + reverse(original), iterations);
> ```

should be:

```
return reverse_add(original + reverse(original), iterations);
```

If the program is working as is, you must be getting lucky.